# WCF The service '/myservice.svc' activated due to an exception during compilation

Tags: wcf, exception

Our current deployment strategy is to deploy all assemblies with each application / service but control where *.exe and service implementaion assemblies are deployed.  With that in mind, I have a specific service that when I deploy 2 unreferenced resource assemblies I get a compilation error.  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '****.resources, Version=1.0.1262.0, Culture=fr, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

I do not have the sub folders for each language deployed in the bin folder e,g, "fr" etc.

Can somebody tell me why these "unreferenced" assemblies are causing compilation errors?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this kind of error can be attributed to a View referencing a resource by a resource key.  This would cause an ASP.NET compile time error.

You can check to see what the requesting DLL is by using fuslogvw.exe to figure out what the binding error is.  If it's a DLL with an obscure name like ASP.jwnca.dll this is probably the case.

Why not just deploy these files?

Hope this helps.